# How to add RGB color code in Tailwind Css?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to replace the default color palette with my own custom colors, add RGB color codes directly under the `theme.colors` section in configuration file.

Comment: But [what is your actual question](/help/how-to-ask) (because notice that you haven't asked a question in your post at all at the moment), and what did you already try, based on what you found online already?

Comment: Question is about adding RGB colors in tailwind configuration. I saw tailwind css customizing colors documentation they didn't shown information about adding RGB color codes in theme.color section.

Comment: Don't tell me: [update your post](/help/how-to-ask). Remember that if you're posting to SO, you need to say 1) what you want to do, 2) what code you wrote to do that, 3) what that code did instead of what it should have done, and 4) what you already tried to fix the problem. In this case, you haven't even gotten to (2) yet so you need to explain why you've written this question instead of searching the web and SO for people who already needed to do this (because it's _possible_ even if highly unlikely, that you're the first person asking this on SO).

Answer (score 2):

You could add them as you mentioned in `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // ...
    },
    colors:{
      green:'rgb(12,159,100)'
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use it like bellow :

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "10rem",
    },
    extend: {},
    colors:{
      primary : {
        light:'#00976A',
        dark:'#4EBE86',
      },
      border :'rgb (161,161,161,50%)'
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```